# xcode not recognizing screen size height 677

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-6

I have an app I am updating because of the Launch Screen requirement instead of launch images.
In so doing I came up with many many warnings that "views without any layout constrainsts may clip their content or overlap other views".  When I went in and tried to address the problem no matter what I did the warnings multiplied.  So I am attempting to rewrite my code to get the screen size and place and size my objects for each phone.  The problem is that Xcode apparently does not recognize iPhone 6 screen size on the actual device.  In the simulator iPhone 8 is recognized but I don't have an actual iPhone 8 to try out.  I would assume it is the same size as the iPhone 6. I have looked on line and I saw this was a problem and possible fixes were to "make sure iPhone 6 launch images were available", but since launch images are no longer that isn't a solution. I also tried

```
if([UIScreen mainScreen].fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.size.height == 667.0){
```

also but that didn't help either.
I can't believe Apple doesn't want to have developers not get the screen size for iPhone 6.
Is there a work around or new way to get screen size for iPhone 6?
Does this problem happen on iPhone 7 and 8 and iPhone 6,7,8 +?
I just saw that I have to include specific sized launch images with my launch screen with specific names.  Is this true?  How do I do this?  Is there a GOOD tutorial?
I am at my wits end and need a solution.
I found a place where I created and installed images for all iphone and ipad portrait sizes and put them in Launchimage in my image asset folder.  my app only runs in portrait so I didn't think I needed to make landscape images.  Anyway, even with all the correct size images, iphone 6 4.7" and 5.5" it still launches seeing the iphone 6 as a 5.  In fact now it launches with a blank screen no launch images showing up at all.

So I added the landscape views and had forgotten an iphone portrait view.  Now in the simulator iphone 8 and 8+ are recognized as the correct device by height but the launch image still isn't loading for iphone 8 and 8+ as well as ipad 7gen, air3gen, and pro 9.7.  Only loads images for iphone11, 11pro, 11promax and ipad pro11 and 12.9. 
On the actual iphone 6 the launch images isn't loaded and it still is recognized as an iphone 5.  This has to be a Mess up by Apple.

Suggestions?
Thanks